# Compilers who are supports DirectX 11 libraries

Tags: c++, directx-11

Which compilers other than Visual Studio 2010 and 2008 support DirectX SDK Jun 2010?

I am a beginner, and I want to program with DirectX 11, but i have a VERY limited internet and may download only little files (300 MB).

It would be interesting to know all compilers that can be used to program for DirectX 11.

Comment: I expect all compilers that can target Windows can target DX11.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short list of compilers that actually include the headers and/or libraries of DirectX 10/11 of the box:

- TDM-GCC x64 builds starting with version 4.7 ship with DirectX 10/11 headers and libraries: http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/
- TDM-GCC x64 build 4.6.1 ships with most DirectX 10/11 headers and libraries, but has limited DWM API support out of the box: the libaries for x86 are missing and some headers are incorrect: https://sourceforge.net/p/tdm-gcc/feature-requests/27/
- Plain Windows GCC (MinGW) does not include anything of DirectX 10/11, but supports a limited part of DirectX 9 out of the box (for example, D3DX is not included).
- The TDM-GCC 4.6.1 builds of Orwell Dev-C++ include DirectX 9/10/11 headers and libraries. They are provided by the Jun 2010 SDK, and libraries are converted to GCC .a format: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/.

Actually, any reasonably modern Windows compiler should be able to compile/support the DirectX 10/11 **headers**. I have seen GCC 3.4.2 struggle a lot though, but that version is ancient. Headers are the easy part, so to speak: simply dump the headers in the appropriate include folder and your compiler suddenly supports DirectX 10/11.

The other part, **libaries**, are the harder part. Obtaining both x64 and x64 libs and converting to GCC's .a (using lib2a) can be annoying. Fortunately, compilers like TDM-GCC or IDEs like Dev-C++ started shipping with the libs a while ago. And again, pretty much any recent compiler will suddenly support DirectX 10/11 if you dump the .a files of the libraries in the proper folder.